# concatenate nested arrays in an array list

Tags: arrays, groovy

I want to have an array list of items with unique fields but also a base or default set of fields they use and can overwrite.

Doing this (below) does almost everything I want- by just looping over all the list items and concatenating with a list of my "default" fields. so for example field2 will be set to `"222222222222222"` if not specified but if it is specified (like in the first item) it overwrites it. What I would also like though is for nested arrays (field4) to not be totally overwritten but instead append. So in my example the field4 in the items in arrCombine would not overwrite `["defaultValue"]` with their own but add to it- like `['defaultValue','one','four']` and `['defaultValue','one','two']`. Is there a groovyism/shortcut for doing this?

```
def arrNewItems = [
        [
                "field1"                   : "zzzzz",
                "field2"                  : 'eeeeeee',
                "field3"                  : 'wwwwwwwwwwww',
                "field4"                  : ['one','four'],
        ],
        [
                "field1"                   : "zzzzz",
                "field3"                  : 'sldkjflskdjflksdjf',
                "field4"                  : ['one','two'],
        ],
]

arrCombine = arrNewItems.collect {item ->
        defaultData = [
                "field1"                  : "111111111111111",
                "field2"                  : "222222222222222",
                "field3"                  : "333333333333333",
                "field4"                  : ["defaultValue"],
                "field5"                  : "555555555555555",
        ]
        return item + defaultData
}
println arrCombine
```

Answer (score 0):

I won't claim this is pretty, but the following code:

```
def a = [
  [
    "field1": "zzzzz",
    "field2": 'eeeeeee',
    "field3": 'wwwwwwwwwwww',
    "field4": ['one','four'],
  ],
  [
    "field1": "zzzzz",
    "field3": 'sldkjflskdjflksdjf',
    "field4": ['one','two'],
  ],
]

def b = [
  "field1": "111111111111111",
  "field2": "222222222222222",
  "field3": "333333333333333",
  "field4": ["defaultValue"],
  "field5": "555555555555555",
]

def c = a.collect { am ->
  am.collectEntries { k, av -> 
    def bv = b[k]
    if (av instanceof List && 
        bv instanceof List)   [k, av + bv] 
    else if (bv == null)      [k, av]
    else                      [k, bv]
  } + b.findAll { k, v -> !am[k] }
}

c.each { m -> 
  println "-----"
  m.each { k, v -> 
    println "$k -> $v"
  }
}
```

when run, produces:

```
─➤ groovy solution.groovy
-----
field1 -> 111111111111111
field2 -> 222222222222222
field3 -> 333333333333333
field4 -> [one, four, defaultValue]
field5 -> 555555555555555
-----
field1 -> 111111111111111
field3 -> 333333333333333
field4 -> [one, two, defaultValue]
field2 -> 222222222222222
field5 -> 555555555555555
```

This problem makes me wish there was a groovy `map.plus(otherMap) { k1, v1, k2, v2 -> ... }` method or something similar, i.e. a customization of the `map + map` construct. No such luck. This is the least ugly I could make it.

Also you can reverse the order of `[one, four, defaultValue]` by just changing the code from `bv instanceof List)   [k, av + bv]` to `bv instanceof List)   [k, bv + av]`.